# Angular directive won't set scope object

Tags: angularjs, timepicker

I am trying to use this bootstrap-timepicker: http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

I set it up in my html like this:

```
          <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
            <input my-timepicker="newSession.time" ng-model="newSession.time.value" type="text" class="input-small">
            <button type="button" class="add-on" style="padding: 2px 6px; height: 26px;"><i class="icon-time"></i></button>
          </div>
```

And then I have created a directive to start it up and keep the model updated.

```
directives.directive('myTimepicker', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(ev) {
        var model = scope.$eval(attrs.myTimepicker);
        model = angular.copy(ev.time);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

With all the breakpoints this can stand, I've found that the model does correctly get set to the scope object `newSession.time`. And, `ev.time` does equal the time object. Yet setting the one equal to the other does nothing it seems. No matter how deep into the scope I look.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that Angular doesn't know you changed anything. Angular doesn't know about `timepicker().on` so it can't fire a digest. The simplest solution is to wrap it in a `$timeout` which will force a digest or do  `$scope.$apply` which is technically more correct.

It might also be easier just to use an isolated scope with two-way binding.

```
directives.directive('myTimepicker', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
 return {
  scope: {myTimepicker:'='},
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $(element).timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(ev) {
      $timeout(function(){
        scope.myTimepicker = ev.time;
      });
    });
  }
  };
}]);
```

scope.apply version:

```
directives.directive('myTimepicker', [function () {
 return {
  scope: {myTimepicker:'='},
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $(element).timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(ev) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.myTimepicker = ev.time;
      });
    });
  }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I'll try the latter. But what do you mean by two-way binding to the isolated scope?

Comment: Isolated scope just means you no-longer share the scope between the directive and where it is located. Using an isolated scope can lead to greater flexibility and decoupling, although the way you're doing it is not tightly coupled so that's okay. But it's just easier because it lets you basically "pass" a variable to a new "isolated" scope in the directive. scope.myTimepicker binds two ways to whatever is passed in. Checkout the docs on angular directives and isolated scopes.

Comment: Is there any way to pass in the object to bind to through an attr. Not finding one in the docs. This solved my issue by the way. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Well, that's what the isolated scope is doing. the = just means two-way binding. But you can just do it like you originally had it if you insist. I'm just partial to isolated scopes.

Comment: Gotcha. Last question - having an issue. I set up an object in the controller: `scope.newSession = {name: '', time: {}};` and then I use your directive but with `scope: {newSession: '='},` and then I do `scope.newSession.time = ev.time`
Problem is, I get an error because scope.newSession is undefined... Ideas? Thanks a lot for your help Jonathan.

Comment: I also get this error: `Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: myTimepicker)`

Comment: the non-assignable model is usually caused by using {{}} in the attribute where you should just put the obj reference in. As for your other error, I think I'd need to see your whole code sample or a plnkr or fiddle.